# Change for loop to Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I can change my loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < something; i++)
```

to:

```
Parallel.For(0, something, i =>
```

But how to do this with this loop?:

```
for (i = 3; i <= something / 2; i = i + 2)
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since

```
for (int i = 3; i <= something / 2; i = i + 2)
{
    ...
}
```

can be rewritten into

```
for (int k = 1; k < (something + 2) / 4; ++k)
{
    int i = 1 + 2 * k;
    ...
}
```

you can put

```
Parallel.For(1, (something + 2) / 4, k =>
{
    int i = 1 + 2 * k; 
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter is a `delegate`. So every iteration you could specify what your indexing variable shall do inside the delegate.

**EDIT:**  Ok found a working solution:
As already suggested by Dmitry Bychenko you should still start from 0 and just add the `startValue` as an offset

```
int something = 16;

int startValue = 3;
int stepSize = 2;

List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToList();

Parallel.For(0, something / 2, i => 
{
    int ind = (stepSize * i) + startValue ; Console.WriteLine(numbers[ind]);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't do what he asks. your code runs for the values 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 in parallel, while he wants it to be equivalent to the loop which skips every second item (values: 3, 5, 7).

Comment: Note that changing `i` inside the `delegate` doesn't change the `Parallel.For` count and it's only a copied value type - `int`.

Comment: Don't you mean:

`var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Where(i => i % 2 == 0).ToList();`

`Parallel.For(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });`

Comment: @ilivewithian this does not solve the problem. The OP had in mind to write the correct For-loop and not fiddle with the data.

Comment: @TamirVered thank you for pointing out the workings of `i`. It really was enlighting

Answer (score 1):

*Dmitry Bychenko*'s answer get it but you could also implement your own `ParallelFor` with custom step which will make your code somewhat more readable:

```
static void ParallelFor(int start, int last, Func<int, int> step, Action<int> action)
{
    var enumerable = StepEnumerable<int>
        .Create(start, step)
        .TakeWhile(x => x < last);

    Parallel.ForEach(enumerable, action);
}
```

Here is `StepEnumerable`'s implementation:

```
public class StepEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    ...

    public StepEnumerable(T value, Func<T, T> manipulation)
    {
        mEnumerator = new StepEnumerator<T>(value, manipulation);
    }

    public static StepEnumerable<T> Create(T value, Func<T, T> manipulation)
    {
        return new StepEnumerable<T>(value, manipulation);
    }

    ...
}

public class StepEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        Current = mManipulation(Current);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then, for example, if you run the following code:

```
ParallelFor(3, 16, x => x + 2, Console.WriteLine);
```

You'll get the following output (In separate lines of course):

> 5, 11, 7, 13, 9, 15